# loading initial data required by all the JUNIT tests and Rollback

Tags: spring, junit

How can we load data which will be used by the JUNIT tests and at the end roll back using spring unit testing?

Comment: please be more specific. What do you mean by rollback? is `@Before` or `@BeforeClass` not sufficient?

Comment: yes, load initial data required by the junit tests and after the unit tests are done erase the data. The need for this is to run the unit test without overcrowding the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your test class extend something like:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.html

See sections 9.3.2.3 and 9.3.5.4 the Spring documentation for further info:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testing-tx

You can use this in conjunction with something like DBUnit to populate your database with known data.

Comment: Found the answer. Use of AbstractTransactionalJunit4SpringContextTest makes all methods transactional. Annotating method with @Transactional does the trick. Rollback is by default.